# PHP getting black image while taking screenshot

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser, com, screenshot

I use the code below and then save the result in a jpg file. But sometimes I get only a black image. It is not happening all the time, what can I do to prevent it? No error is thrown, only some screenshots are black. And I run it on Windows.

```
 $browser = new com('internetexplorer.application');
    $browserhandle = $browser->hwnd;
    $browser->visible = true;
    $browser->fullscreen = true;
    $browser->navigate('http://www.example.com');
    while ($browser->busy) {
        com_message_pump(1000);
        if ($timer + $timelimit < time()) {
            $browser->stop();
            break;
        }
    }
    sleep(5);
    $img = imagegrabwindow($browserhandle, 0);
    $browser->Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sleep(5)` after `imagegrabwindow(...)`

It helped me solve the same problem

my code is :

```
$im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
imagejpeg($im, "test.jpg");
sleep(5);
$browser->Quit();
imagedestroy($im);
```